# Importance of /a in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Fristly I would like to apologize if question is simple but I am having hard time in understanding the piece of code in batch file.

what is `/a` in below code and what is its importance and what does it do?

```
if %first%==1 set /a id=(%3-1) * 3
```

here I understand `id` is variable to store the value and `%first%` is I am getting the value from this variable, But I couldn't understand `/a`.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Try running `set /?` at the command prompt. set /a means use arithmetic - expects everything to the right of the equals sign to be numeric. So the command line parameter %3 must be a number for this equation to work

Comment: @ScottC thanks for your clear explanation... is there any online link available to know the commands starting with `/`, If yes can you provide me. Thanks. you can answer the question I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get help on most commands from the command prompt by typing: commandName /?

e.g.

```
set /?
for /?
```

http://www.computerhope.com/msdos.htm is a pretty good online help for dos commands.

Comment: Thanks but in command line when I typed `Set /a` then I got message `Syntax of command is incorrect`. why is this happening.

Comment: `set /a` needs some parameters, `set` is the command. `set /?` gives you usage information where you will find information about the extra parameters that `set /a` uses.

Answer (score 3):

`set /a ...` indicates an arithmetic expression.

**Reference** [Set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html):

> Arithmetic expressions (SET /a)
>
> The expression to be evaluated can include the following operators:
>
> ```
>    +   Add                set /a "_num=_num+5"
>    +=  Add variable       set /a "_num+=5"
>    -   Subtract (or unary)set /a "_num=_num-5"
>    -=  Subtract variable  set /a "_num-=5"
>    *   Multiply           set /a "_num=_num*5"
>    *=  Multiply variable  set /a "_num*=5"
>    /   Divide             set /a "_num=_num/5"
>    /=  Divide variable    set /a "_num/=5"
>    %   Modulus            set /a "_num=5%%2"
>    %%= Modulus            set /a "_num%%=5" 
>    !   Logical negation  0 (FALSE) ⇨ 1 (TRUE) and any non-zero value (TRUE) ⇨ 0 (FALSE)
>    ~   One's complement (bitwise negation) 
>    &   AND                set /a "_num=5&3"    0101 AND 0011 = 0001 (decimal 1)
>    &=  AND variable       set /a "_num&=3"
>    |   OR                 set /a "_num=5|3"    0101 OR 0011 = 0111 (decimal 7)
>    |=  OR variable        set /a "_num|=3"
>    ^   XOR                set /a "_num=5^3"    0101 XOR 0011 = 0110 (decimal 6)
>    ^=  XOR variable       set /a "_num=^3"
>    <<  Left Shift.    (sign bit ⇨ 0)
>    >>  Right Shift.   (Fills in the sign bit such that a negative number always remains negative.)
>                        Neither ShiftRight nor ShiftLeft will detect overflow.
>    <<= Left Shift variable     set /a _num<<=2
>    >>= Right Shift variable    set /a _num>>=2
>
>   ( )  Parenthesis group expressions  set /a "_num=(2+3)*5"
>    ,   Commas separate expressions    set /a "_num=2,_result=_num*5"
> ```

...

> **Arithmetic expressions (SET /a)**
>
> Placing expressions in "quotes" is optional for simple arithmetic but
>   required for any expression using logical operators.
>
> Any SET /A calculation that returns a fractional result will be
>   rounded down to the nearest whole integer.
>
> **Examples:**
>
> ```
> SET /A "_result=2+4" (=6)
>
> SET /A "_result=5" (=5)
> SET /A "_result+=5" (=10)
>
> SET /A "_result=2<<3" (=16) { 2 Lsh 3 = binary 10 Lsh 3 = binary 10000 = decimal 16 }
>
> SET /A "_result=5%%2" (=1) { 5/2 = 2 + 2 remainder 1 = 1 }
> ```
>
> In a batch script, the Modulus operator (%) must be doubled up to
>   (%%).
>
> SET /A will treat any character string in the expression as an
>   environment variable name. This allows you to do arithmetic with
>   environment variables without having to type any % signs to get the
>   values.
>
> ```
> SET /A _result=5 + _MyVar
> ```
>
> Multiple calculations can be performed in one line, by separating each
>   calculation with commas, for example:
>
> ```
> _year=1999 Set /a _century=_year/100, _next=_century+1
> ```
>
> The numbers must all be within the range of 32 bit signed integer
>   numbers (-2,147,483,648 through 2,147,483,647) to handle larger
>   numbers use PowerShell or VBScript. Leading Zero will specify Octal
>
> Numeric values are decimal numbers, unless prefixed by 0x for
>   hexadecimal numbers, 0 for octal numbers.
>
> So 0x10 = 020 = 16 decimal
>
> The octal notation can be confusing - all numeric values that start
>   with zeros are treated as octal but 08 and 09 are not valid octal
>   digits. For example SET /a _month=07 will return the value 7, but SET
>   /a _month=09 will return an error.

See [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) for information on other Windows command line commands.